# Getting all the objects from a bookmark without mapping

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I am working on a platform that allows student search and get a house. I am trying to implement a feature that allows students bookmark a house so they can come check it for later purpose. The issue I am having is how to retrieve the houses the user already bookmarked. I currently do it via mapping but that results in a nested array. I know there is a way I can do it without mapping. I would appreciate any help.

BookmarkController.php

```php
public function userBookmarks()
{
    $user = $this->authUser();
    $bookmarks = Bookmark::where('user_id', $user->id)->get();
    if (count($bookmarks) > 0) {
        $bookmark = $bookmarks->map(function ($favorite, $key) {
            $response = [
                "status" => true,
                "message" => "User's favorites successfully retrieved",
                "data" => House::find($bookmark->house_id),
            ];
            return $response;
        });
        return response()->json($bookmark);
    } else {
        return response()->json([
            "message" => "This user doesn't have any favorites yet",
            "data" => null,
        ]);
    }
}
```

User.php

```
public function bookmarks(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Favorite');
    }
```

Bookmark.php

```
public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to come up with a solution.

```
public function userFavorites(){
        $user = $this->authUser();
        $bookmarks = $user->bookmarks;
        if(!empty($bookmarks)){
            $houseIds = $bookmarks->pluck('house_id');
            $houses = House::whereIn('id',$houseIds)->get();
            $response = [
                "status" => true, 
                "message" => "User's bookmarks successfully retrieved", 
                "data" => $houses
            ];
            return response()->json($response);
        }
        else
        {
            return response()->json([
            "status"=> true,
            "message" => "This user doesn't have any bookmarks yet",
            "data" => null
            ]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's why inside the `map` function, the `$booksmark` var doesn't exist!

I guess you mean `$favourite` (take a look at the params you pass in the anonymous function).

Take a look at this code:

```php
public function userBookmarks()
{
    $bookmarks = Bookmark::where('user_id', $this->authUser()->id)->get();

    if (empty($bookmarks)) {
        return response()->json([
            "message" => "This user doesn't have any favorites yet",
            "data"    => null,
        ]);
    }

    $bookmark = $bookmarks->map(function (Bookmark $favorite): array {
        return [
            "status"  => true,
            "message" => "User's favorites successfully retrieved",
            "data"    => House::find($favorite->house_id),
        ];
    });

    return response()->json($bookmark);
}
```

---

Edit: If you want to pass a var inside the anonymous function, it's possible with the `use` keyword.
Something similar to (in case `$favourite` comes from somewhere else):

```php
$fixedPrice = 100;
$items->map(function(Item $item) use ($fixedPrice): array {
    return [
        'id'    => $item->id,
        'price' => $fixedPrice.
    ];
});
```

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is: I don't want to have a nested array. I am thinking if there is any other eloquent query I could write to give me the same result without having a nested array.

Comment: You need to create the eloquent relationship between `House` and `Bookmark` (if they already don't exist). Using the `select` eloquent method you can filter the data you need, and with `with()` you can achieve the data field, but if you want a json response with an expecific result, I think you have to map the collection as you did.

Comment: From what I wrote in the question, I don't want to map, is there a way I can write an eloquent query to achieve that?

Comment: There is a relationship already. It is a one to many relationship but I don't have an idea of the eloquent query I need to write please can you help out?

Comment: I have just replied in my previous comment. I don't think so but if it exists, I don't know. :)

Comment: The query would be something similar to: `$bookmarks = Bookmark::select(['type', 'the', 'columns', 'you', 'need'])->where('user_id', $user->id)->with('houses.id')->get();`. I need to check the documentation for the `with()` but that is the idea.